# How do I deploy a contract with payable constructor with Brownie python

Tags: solidity, blockchain, brownie

I have a constructor in my Smart Contract:

```
constructor() payable
{
    require(msg.value >= 100000000 gwei, "Min == 0.1ETH");
    require(msg.value <= 500000000 gwei, "Max == 0.5ETH");
}
```

How do I deploy it on brownie? I know of the

```
deploy_wallet = contractName.deploy({"from": account})
```

How do I pass the eth value?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add one thing to your python deployment code which is "value" - you pass value in wei.

```
deploy_wallet = contractName.deploy({"from": account, "value": 1000})
```